# After grouping, how to order the list with preferences (particular field names)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, c#-4.0

Code :

```
var recordsList = list.GroupBy(u => u.state)
                                        .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                                        .ToList();
```

`state` field has values such as `Approved`, `Review`, `Planning`, `Scheduled`.
I want to order the records as group with first fetching `state` having `Approved`, then `state` having `Review`, then `state` having `Planning` and atlast to display the `state` having `Scheduled` records..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
var recordsList = list.GroupBy(u => u.state)
    .OrderBy(grp => StateToOrder(grp.Key))
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

this method is for Ordering your different state

```
public int StateToOrder(string state)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case "Approved":
                return 1;
            case "Review":
                return 2;
            case "Planning":
                return 3;
            case "Scheduled":
                return 4;
            default:
                return 5;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If those field values are mapped to an Enum (int), then the ordering should work just fine?

If possible at all, change the string property to an Enum you define yourself. Then you can use this to order:

```
var recordsList = list.GroupBy(u => u.state)
                      .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
                      .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
                      .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you could create your own Comparer, which orders in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) (where `T` is whatever type `state` is) to reflect your sort order.

You can then sort your groups by `Key` (which is the `state`) using `OrderBy` and your `comparer` instance:

```
var recordsList = list.GroupBy(u => u.state)
    .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key, comparer)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

A very basic implementation of the comparer might be:

```
public class StateComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly List<string> Order = new List<string>
    {
        "Approved",
        "Review",
        "Planning",
        "Scheduled"
    };

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return Order.IndexOf(x).CompareTo(Order.IndexOf(y));
    }
}
```

Comment: `state` is a `string` type

Comment: How to implement `IComparer<T>` ?

Comment: There are examples in the linked documentation.

Comment: In my question, I am having the `4` states which is the correct order. I want to order in that pattern. Thanks.

Comment: Please give the example for `comparer`

Comment: @StackOverflow This isn't a code writing service, you should at least go and look how to implement a comparer yourself.  There are examples in the documentation. I've now added a basic example.

Comment: Ok, My doubt is that how `comparer` in the above code knows the values ? Because same `comparer` word is not used anywhere above other than that. Thanks.

Comment: @StackOverflow knows what values?

Comment: Is comparer a variable ?

Comment: @StackOverflow comparer is an instance of the comparer, e.g. `var comparer = new StateComparer()`.